# Division of rows based on common element in a column in R

Tags: r

I want to divide row containing "SouthAsia" by row containing "World" if they share a common Item in column viz., "Wheat" or "Maize".
The data is given here below. This row division between each pair of rows then finally produces new set of rows displaying ratio for each Item.

```
structure(list(Area = c("SouthAsia", "SouthAsia", "SouthAsia", 
"World", "World", "World"), Item = c("Maize", "Rice, paddy", 
"Wheat", "Maize", "Rice, paddy", "Wheat"), Y1961 = c(6407211, 
72997704, 17262512, 205027583, 215646633, 222357231), Y1962 = c(6695859, 
68267587, 18559724, 204876937, 226456297, 250319146), Y1963 = c(6714951, 
76732860, 17080482, 220228333, 247119211, 233339473), Y1964 = c(6831133, 
80435637, 16423344, 215172627, 262928956, 268791657), Y1965 = c(7005474, 
67001202, 19294944, 226544256, 254059664, 263645963), Y1966 = c(7093056, 
65434054, 16531200, 245599160, 261181258, 303785460), Y1967 = c(8651161, 
79139887, 18225700, 272548473, 277386363, 294295876), Y1968 = c(7939113, 
83689109, 25581957, 255670551, 288624308, 326843941), Y1969 = c(8002216, 
86322032, 28056080, 269506068, 295584391, 308640283), Y1970 = c(9783128, 
87683244, 29844066, 265831145, 316345703, 310740954), Y1971 = c(7313007, 
87027895, 32534949, 313622622, 317712426, 347525581), Y1972 = c(8719066, 
81267738, 36095761, 308826290, 307289937, 343001429), Y1973 = c(8234869, 
91819170, 35287635, 318290469, 334928838, 369334126), Y1974 = c(7995945, 
84574295, 32583021, 306427347, 331970614, 358825442), Y1975 = c(9685425, 
100665720, 35082769, 341751971, 356963090, 355806146), Y1976 = c(8822957, 
88925298, 41085798, 352395866, 347686462, 419868031), Y1977 = c(8387591, 
107294218, 41434886, 371593355, 369481153, 382276677), Y1978 = c(8614790, 
109810429, 43696667, 393600091, 385208745, 443844880), Y1979 = c(7912276, 
91880021, 49038269, 418622993, 375251758, 422999301), Y1980 = c(9522417, 
110886917, 46507696, 396623388, 396871310, 440187901), Y1981 = c(9384164, 
110710256, 51836211, 446772517, 410075231, 449633986), Y1982 = c(9039403, 
101674135, 52650327, 448932280, 421949049, 476768609), Y1983 = c(10448333, 
122468764, 59277304, 347082034, 448016295, 489555281), Y1984 = c(11012971, 
119988187, 60408803, 450449992, 465342898, 512330225), Y1985 = c(9213370, 
128597085, 59861150, 485527301, 468164572, 499527392), Y1986 = c(10256390, 
124478637, 64550633, 478176622, 468675242, 528685222), Y1987 = c(8358274, 
118819340, 60438826, 453115794, 461439908, 505075847), Y1988 = c(11071222, 
140631528, 62541223, 403050234, 487457902, 500656538), Y1989 = c(12554629, 
147741345, 72185508, 476874503, 514421640, 538206114), Y1990 = c(11933890, 
149614829, 67564964, 483620724, 518568653, 591330111), Y1991 = c(10970830, 
150132983, 73270756, 494407622, 518512573, 547820731), Y1992 = c(12837725, 
146312212, 74855714, 533789336, 527878059, 565111947), Y1993 = c(12578385, 
159727295, 77254230, 477221153, 529599553, 564739765), Y1994 = c(12069881, 
158910620, 79142892, 568663564, 538591048, 525435323), Y1995 = c(12977637, 
154617470, 87041790, 517299059, 547162009, 544357532), Y1996 = c(14066718, 
163300843, 83703860, 586146163, 568658031, 578616933), Y1997 = c(14063179, 
164680914, 91257800, 584411894, 577136893, 614651780), Y1998 = c(14631874, 
172666586, 90696585, 615081853, 578813977, 596175815), Y1999 = c(14852980, 
183677669, 94658584, 607434709, 611177579, 584763438), Y2000 = c(15305800, 
179676961, 101944376, 592038698, 598668171, 584999160), Y2001 = c(16621797, 
189133767, 93136961, 615152413, 600246617, 588243664), Y2002 = c(14882647, 
159458525, 96547431, 603551954, 571051228, 591981086), Y2003 = c(18857426, 
186104422, 91279765, 645055272, 586931423, 550094673), Y2004 = c(19323988, 
176071326, 96690762, 729517951, 607348698, 634872610), Y2005 = c(20342590, 
193895321, 96944929, 714191174, 634225091, 626942336), Y2006 = c(20927951, 
196231384, 96132622, 707937211, 640705012, 614538223), Y2007 = c(25783344, 
203534371, 105846322, 792732888, 656556273, 606681083), Y2008 = c(27114670, 
214069655, 104573893, 829240208, 687050383, 680953900), Y2009 = c(23132226, 
203027798, 111973789, 820072448, 685656731, 684127032), Y2010 = c(28695638, 
210327238, 111109302, 851679519, 701138548, 640258978), Y2011 = c(29701932, 
226873498, 118199962, 886680581, 726376264, 697614006), Y2012 = c(30542405, 
226097053, 126249936, 875039160, 736596755, 672694662), Y2013 = c(33336640, 
230917477, 125878251, 1016207182, 742504938, 710947981), Y2014 = c(34145483, 
228552461, 130390977, 1039267776, 742438725, 726302081), Y2015 = c(32876833, 
227056973, 119616569, 1052097073, 745337946, 751863360), Y2016 = c(37319955, 
232127209, 125565666, 1100225518, 756158217, 749014842), Y2017 = c(40206832, 
235930376, 132659258, 1134746667, 769657791, 771718579)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want a new dataframe that gives this ratio for each Item. The use of ifelse condition appears to be one of the possible choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off using the long table format for such data analysis. Here's a way using `dplyr` and `tidyr` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

result <- df %>% 
  gather(year, value, -Item, -Area) %>% 
  spread(Area, value) %>% 
  mutate(
    WorldPct = SouthAsia/World
  )

head(result, 10)

    Item  year SouthAsia     World   WorldPct
1  Maize Y1961   6407211 205027583 0.03125048
2  Maize Y1962   6695859 204876937 0.03268235
3  Maize Y1963   6714951 220228333 0.03049086
4  Maize Y1964   6831133 215172627 0.03174722
5  Maize Y1965   7005474 226544256 0.03092320
6  Maize Y1966   7093056 245599160 0.02888062
7  Maize Y1967   8651161 272548473 0.03174173
8  Maize Y1968   7939113 255670551 0.03105212
9  Maize Y1969   8002216 269506068 0.02969216
10 Maize Y1970   9783128 265831145 0.03680204
```